# css import font doesn't work

Tags: css, fonts

I have some problem in my p element.

here is my html and css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Raleway Medium';
    src: url('Raleway-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
.item_txt{
    padding-top : 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 95px;
    font-size: 21px;
    color : #F9F9F9;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Raleway Medium' !important;
}
```

I tried to import custom font but it failed.

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2">

            <div class="item_box">
                <img src="images/boardicon1.png" class='item_img'>
                <p class="item_txt">Mother Board</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

ႈhere is project directory.

[image]

Comment: Did you fix your problem?

Comment: not yet bro :( it still doesn't work

Comment: Any errors in the console with my code? Or any other problems?

Comment: just another problem.

Comment: i got the right answer. @import dooesn't work but importing standard way get me the right output. Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your style sheet:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
```

Than use this to use the font on certain elements:

```
p {
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it works fine if the computer you are rendering it has the font installed  as TrueType font, **but** if this is on web and the user that renders that page does not have that font installed locally it will fallback to browser default or your default if defined. You need to use a web version of that font, woff or woff2. Using google font will get you back the web version even if you don't ask for it. Search for the woff/woff2 version of the font and us that.

Comment: i generated woff versions with fontsquarrel and then it still doesn't work . I have no idea why :( . I used custom fonts in many times before.But I can't find what is wrong in this project :(

Comment: seem like it may be caused by Bootstrap css settings?