# Changing font-family in class

Tags: html, css, class, font-family

This is a really simple question that I can't figure out the answer to. I am a total beginner.
I can't change the font-family for some reason. I can physically type something different but it doesn't change the font at all. This is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCUTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Fruit</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
.left {
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:#FFEBCD;
    border:2px solid black;
    font-family: 'Alegreya SC';font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="left">
    <h1><strong>Fruit</strong></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using custom fonts using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css) or [this answer for using import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259509/css-import-font-doesnt-work/44259654#44259654) You need to include the font so that it can be used.

Comment: you miss </div>

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the desired font ( google font in your case ) inside your project.
You can do that in multiple ways. One is adding a link to it in your HTML

You can also that a quick look at this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started)

Other ways:

- import in your stylesheet (CSS) with `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+SC');`  or
- download the font and include it in your project and then import it
  with `@import(pathToFont)`

```css
.left {
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:#FFEBCD;
    border:2px solid black;
    font-family: 'Alegreya SC', serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="left">
  <h1>
  AAAA
  </h1>
</div>
```